# how to use vimeo advanced API to display videos

Tags: php, api, vimeo, vimeo-api

I was using the Vimeo simple API to display the videos from a channel on my website, but as you may know, it has a limit. I was wondering if you could give me an example of how to use the advanced API. I have read the documentation, But I just don't know how to use those methods (obviously i am not php expert).

So it would be awesome if you could show me one example or any tutorial were I could understand it.

This is Part of the code I was using in the simple API:

```
    var apiEndpoint = 'http://vimeo.com/api/v2/';
var oEmbedEndpoint = 'http://vimeo.com/api/oembed.json'
var oEmbedCallback = 'switchVideo';
var videosCallback = 'setupGallery&iframe=false';

    $(document).ready(function() {
    $.getScript(apiEndpoint + vimeoUsername + '/videos.json?callback=' + videosCallback);
});

    function setupGallery(videos) {         

    for (var i = 0; i < videos.length; i++) {
        var html = '<li><a href="' + videos[i].url +'"alt="'+videos[i].title+'"><img src="' + videos[i].thumbnail_large + '" class="thumb" />';
        html += '<div><p>' + videos[i].title + '</p></div></a></li>';
        $('#thumbs ul').append(html);

    }
```

I just want to do the same but with the advance API (using php).

thanks a lot, I'd appreciate any advise.

Comment: This Q&A might help you understand how to work with the PHP API: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22929081/basic-php-vimeo-advanced-api-call

Answer (score 5):

[edit] **NOTE:** This is the old, advanced API. It is no longer supported by Vimeo, or accessible by new app developers. Please refer to the new upload documentation at https://developer.vimeo.com/api/upload/videos

1. Create an Api APP at developer.vimeo.com/apps
2. Use the official [PHP library](https://github.com/vimeo/vimeo-php-lib)

Once you have that, you need to create your vimeo object

```
// You must replace CONSUMER_KEY and CONSUMER_SECRET with the values from your app
$vimeo = new phpVimeo('CONSUMER_KEY', 'CONSUMER_SECRET');
```

Once you have the vimeo object, you can make api calls using the `call` method. This method takes an [api method](https://developer.vimeo.com/apis/advanced/methods).

```
$videos = $vimeo->call('VIMEO_METHOD');
```

For your specific use case, finding the videos uploaded by a user, you use the method `vimeo.videos.getUploaded`. You can find more documentation (and try it out!) at the [vimeo api playground](https://developer.vimeo.com/apis/advanced/methods/vimeo.videos.getUploaded/playground)

Once you understand all of that, I believe the following code would work for you.

```
$vimeo = new phpVimeo('CONSUMER_KEY', 'CONSUMER_SECRET');
$videos = $vimeo->call('vimeo.videos.getUploaded', array('user_id' => $vimeo_username));
```